# How to implement web sockets in a system with more than a single API server (or in a container-based environment)?

Tags: websocket

Suppose we are trying to build a chat application and the architecture that looks something like this:

[image]

When User 1 sends a message to User 2 through API Server 1, how would you design the system so that API Server 1 knows that User 2 is connected to API Server 2?

How I would approach it would be something like this:

- Whenever a User connects to an API server, we will store the "connection" information (user_id and ip_address of the server) in a database.
- When User 1 sends a message to User 2 through API Server 1, API Server 1 will read the database to find out the IP address of the server which User 2 is connected to. API Server 1 will then make a HTTP POST request to API Server 2 (via IP address) with the message. The flow looks something like this:
  [image]

My questions are:

- Is there a better approach to handling web sockets across multiple servers?
- Suppose API Server 2 crashes, how do you update the database that User 2 is no longer connected to API Server 2? How would you keep the database in-sync with the actual connections to the API Servers?
- How would this architecture look like in a container-based environment? I'm assuming in most container-based environment like Kubernetes, we don't work directly with ip_addresses. What would you store in the database then?